# git workflow challenge for 2-way merging a perpetual branch with some differences that shouldn't be merged

Tags: git

We use git & github for our code repositories.  One of my contract developers is on windows, the rest are not.  The windows dev has had to make some changes to various files in order to make the project work on windows. These changes should never be merged back into the master branch. Other than those changes, he makes commits (including some commits to files that he may have previously made windows-specific commits to) that we want merged back to our master branch (after my review).

My initial attempt at solving for this is failing.  We created a special branch for him "windev" and added it to origin. He's made his initial windows-specific commits to a local windev branch that tracks the remote one, and then carried on working exclusively in this branch, pushing to it.  Initially, I thought, ok I'll just cherry pick his relevant commits, since I don't want to ever merge in his windows-specific commits to our master branch. That works fine to get the good commits into our master branch. The problem is that he also needs to update his windev branch from master periodically to have the latest code base.  We started by trying rebase, but it seemed to create a confusing mess, not handling the cherry-picks or the windows-specific commits well at all.  So, I've been having him merge from the master branch each time he wants to update his code, but the problem with that is that there are duplicate commits in his branch for every one of his commits I've cherry picked. I also suspect these duplicate commits are leading to unnecessary conflicts and potential code loss.

I'm about ready to start over with him, since this seems to be kind of messy and I'm afraid its creating errors or unnecessary, error-prone conflicts. But I'm trying to work out what the best workflow for this situation is and am kind of befuddled.  Any ideas?  (PS He's new to git, and confused by it, so I'm trying to keep it simple for him. I'd prefer to handle any complex parts of the workflow myself. )

Comment: I don't think it is right approach. Source code should be platform independent, so the right thing to do - reorganize source code so that multiplatform stuff will co-exist.

Comment: Kan, our source code is platform independent.  The problem is the build & runtime environment configuration.  But, you are right.  While the solutions below would work, I think i am going to set up a build/run configuration specific to his platform. Its more work for me up front, but allows for a single version of the code.  I'll still keep him on a separate branch, but can easily merge back and forth between the two now without worrying about things getting stomped.

Comment: Just make two different files/folders for both platform specific environments. It is quite important to keep code base flexible enough to such things. Maybe soon you will hire a Mac developer... ;)

Comment: Well, in our case, a python/django web application, the cost to support all the pain and differences that Windows presents, just to be able to use our front-end developer of choice hasn't been very worthwhile.   So I'd say it depends on what you're building how important/costly/feasible it is.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16094589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build a permanent branch for the changes required to get it working on windows, and rebuild `windev` with each feature he writes (i.e. every time he needs to get `master` updated on his local).

This sounds more complicated than it is, and I've used it successfully to manage a long running set of concurrent, mutually exclusive configuration changes in a Tomcat app (i.e. multiple versions of `META-INF/context.xml` for different production environments).

```
git checkout -B permanent master ;# check out a "permanent" branch
< make required windows changes and commit >
git checkout -B windev master ;# this is the branch he uses for new work
git merge permanent ;# merge 'permanent' into 'windev'
```

So now he hacks away for a while. You use `cherry-pick`, which is fine on your end. When he needs to merge `master` back into `windev`, which presumably occurs when he's completed some sort of feature or project and you've cherry-picked his new work in, he just issues:

```
git rebase --onto master master permanent ;# rebase permanent onto newest master
git checkout -B windev master ;# reset 'windev' to 'master'
git merge permanent ;# and merge in the required changes
```

In practice, it's just these last three commands issued every couple of days / weeks. If he's extremely messy, and keeps a lot of WIP around his local, or depends heavily on the work of your other team members, it might not be sufficient. If he's fairly isolated and only has to merge in `master` at logical work points, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by [smudge clean](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) which are hooks he can use to apply his changes before modifying his working directory and remove before commiting. Ideally it would just be a flag telling windows or linux and your application would look at this flag where it is needed.

All other possibilities I can see seem very complicated: he has a *windev* branch which he never pushes which is permanently rebased on */remotes/origin/master*, and he commits on *master* branch but always has to checkout *windev* before running the soft containing the changes he made into *windev*, so not that good.

I think other [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) might be worth it, like one that rebase *windev* on *master* every time he commits on master.

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe I just needed to hear that its not a good fit for git's out of the box tools.  That gives me a basis to rethink the best solution to this.