# Git bi-directional merging

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm wanting to know the best approach for dealing with this git scenario:

Git repo a: CoreProduct

Git repo b: SpecificCustomerProduct which was forked from a

Up until now, we have been making different changes to both  a and b, and only merging a down to b. All good so far - the specific product is gaining features from our CorePoduct

Now, we have ended up with *some* commits in b, that we would like to get back up into a (and there is new stuff in a that also needs to come down to b as usual)

Question: 
What is the best way to get these specific commits from b up to a, with the intent of keeping our more regular merges from a to b as painless as possible moving forward?

Question:
If we were doing this from scratch, how would you do it?

I was thinking of cherrypicking commits from b into a temp branch on b and then 'pull request' that branch up to a, but am concerned about that affecting future merges from a to b..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your repo has such a structure:

```
... --- A1(branch_A)
         \
          \
... ------ B1(branch_B)
```

My suggestion is:

(1) Just in case, backup your branches first by `git branch bak_A branch_A` and `git branch bak_B branch_B`.

(2) `git checkout branch_A`, do the modifications (by cherry-picking or by merging, whatever you want) then commit, you will get a A2 like this (the edge between B1 and A2 may not exists, and it doesn't matter):

```
... --- A1 --- A2(branch_A)
         \    /
          \  /
... ------ B1(branch_B)
```

(3) `git checkout branch_B`, then `git commit-tree branch_B^{tree} -p branch_B -p branch_A -m "<commit messages>" | xargs -I {} git merge {}`, you will get:

```
... --- A1 --- A2(branch_A)
         \    / \
          \  /   \
... ------ B1 --- B2(branch_B)
```

in which B1 and B2 have the same content.

(4) Now you can continue your development as before. If anything goes wrong, you can restore your branches by `git branch -f branch_A bak_A` and `git branch -f branch_B bak_B`.

Comment: I'll try and paraphase your answer to ensure my understanding is correct:


1) Backup for safety if something goes wrong.


2) I should cherry-pick the commits I need from B, committing them into A.


3) I'm not clear of the intent of this step.  I am using the commit-tree command for xyz reason? I think with the intent of ensuring that B can receive merges from A in the future that do not cause pain?  They wont cause pain because ??

Comment: @zadam: Step 3) is to add a new commit B2 with the same content of B1 but have a merging relationship with A2. This step will make your further merges(from A to B) easier.

Comment: @zadam: When merging, git first finds out what the *merge base* is, then merges the differences after the *merge base*. If step 3) is omitted, on your next merging(from A to B) git will take A1 as the *merge base*, and git will try to put all the changes after A1 into B, which is not what you want.

Comment: A and B are separate repos.  From A, I created a remote to B so that I could cherry-pick and then commit to A. So for 3) if I git checkout my branch that is tracking the remote and apply those commands, I would only be doing a commit-tree and merge to the remote tracking branch, not to the 'real' branch in repo B right?  I need to do this to the 'real' branch in the real repo B right? Or can I just do that command to my remote tracking branch and it magically works?

Comment: @zadam: You just need a push to submit your changes to the 'real' branch.

Comment: Thanks @SaltyEgg. I pushed OK to my 'real' branch, then when I wanted to push to our 'central' 'real' branch, I was behind, so did a git pull --rebase, and ended up in an epic rebasing session with merge conflicts on nearly every commit. I'm not sure how future merges from A to B will go!  Anyway, thankyou for taking the time to respond to my questions - much appreciated.

Comment: Because I don't know the details of your repositories, I'm sorry I can't help you more on this problem. Moreover, http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals is a not-too-long document describing the internals of git, and I hope it would help your future usage of git.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Here are a couple of random points I liked to clarify in my head before proceeding. (1) The merge after the commit-tree is simply a fast-forward to move HEAD to the new commit, you can appease your mind with --no-ff or simply use `git reset` instead (no need for --hard, working space hasn't changed) if you don't want a potentially confusing merge entry in your reflog. (2) You can of course reference HEAD^{tree} instead of branch_B^{tree}. (3) `xargs -I` replaces {} in the cmdline by the single line passed via stdin; you can use command substitution instead.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping things in the future as painless as possible make sure that B is up to date with the changes from a via `merge` or `rebase` and then do the process in reverse unto A.  `cherry-pick` is not a good idea as that creates a new commit sha that won't be shared in the histories and could cause trouble down the road.

Doing a `merge` from B to A is the simplest way and will keep things easy going forward.  The history will show the commit coming from B and it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I only want *some* commits from b to go into a.  Is merging still the correct approach?  How do I ensure only the commits I want get merged?

Comment: I didn't see the 'some' in your question, in that case, no, merging is not the correct thing to do. For that, you want do a cherry-pick of the commits that you want in A.